# Range slider component does not default to halfway between min and max

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, slider

As per the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#value), "the default value [for range sliders] is halfway between the specified minimum and maximum..." I have a React component containing an `input` with a type of `range`. I've set the minimum value to 0 and the max to 150. The middle value would be 75, but in React, it's defaulting to 50. Whenever I reproduce in standard HTML, it works as intended, but here in React, it is not. Why is the value defaulting to 50?[image]

Here is my code:

```
// Slider.tsx
const Slider = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="150" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

```
// App.tsx
import Slider from "./components/Slider";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="text-blue-600 text-2xl">Range Slider</h1>
      <Slider />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can confirm [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-type-range-default-xkxzy0?file=/src/App.js:163-172) but can't find a relevant reference in the docs as yet.

Comment: Wild stuff. I'll look through the github repo to see if I find anything.

Comment: Possibly this line: `<input type="range" defaultValue={0.5} />` in the [`range-inputs` fixture](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/fixtures/dom/src/components/fixtures/range-inputs/index.js)

Comment: Seems like you could file an issue to have this looked at in reference to the standard?

Comment: Ah ha! This is it. Thanks for helping me find that. I have since made this input a controlled component, which solved the issue at one level, but it's good to know the meaning behind the behavior.

Yeah, I'll see about writing up an issue for the team.

Comment: A strange case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you are referring to is [the "HTML reference"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#value), which is applicable to writing **HTML code**.

React on the other hand is a **javascript** library, which creates HTML DOM elements directly via the browsers DOM API, and not by parsing HTML code. Here [the "HTML DOM API reference"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) applies, and not the "HTML reference".

E.g. compare creating the input element via HTML code and via the DOM API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML vs DOM example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTML code:</h2>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="150" />

    <h2>DOM API:</h2>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            const inputElement = document.createElement( 'input' );
            inputElement.type = 'range';
            inputElement.min = '0';
            inputElement.max = '150';
            document.getElementById('root').appendChild( inputElement );
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### The `defaultValue` in HTML

When writing HTML code, you define all HTML attributes of the Element at once,
and the browser knows all of them when it wants to create the corresponding DOM nodes.

So the browser is able to calculate the `defaultValue` from the (fixed) `min` and `max` values.
[The HTML reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#value) even tells the algorithm for determining the default value:

```
defaultValue =
  rangeElem.max < rangeElem.min
    ? rangeElem.min
    : rangeElem.min + (rangeElem.max - rangeElem.min) / 2;
```

### The `defaultValue` using the DOM API

When using the DOM API, the browser can not easily calculate the `defaultValue`. Consider this example:

```
const inputElement = document.createElement( 'input' );
inputElement.type = 'range';
inputElement.min = '0';
inputElement.max = '150';
// ...
inputElement.min = '50';
```

Now, there might be a way how the browser should handle this case (or more complicated cases) that makes the most sense, but it is not as obvious anymore, and might be controversial.

And, as you are manipulating the DOM anyway, it makes sense to leave it up to you to set the `defaultValue` (or the `value`, anyway).

*(The input element has to have *some* value, so I guess the `50` was just chosen because the default for `min` and `max` is `0` and `100`.)*

You might use the same algorithm as the HTML element does:

```
const inputElement = document.createElement( 'input' );
const range = { min: 0, max: 150 };
inputElement.type = 'range';
inputElement.min = '' + range.min;
inputElement.max = '' + range.max;
inputElement.value = 
    range.max < range.min
        ? range.min
        : range.min + (range.max - range.min) / 2;
```

Or in React:

```
function App() {
    const range = { min: 0, max: 150 };
    
    const defaultValue =
        range.max < range.min
            ? range.min
            : range.min + (range.max - range.min) / 2;

    return <input
        type="range"
        min={ range.min }
        max={ range.max }
        defaultValue={ defaultValue }
    />;
}
```